# ScrollView - detect only when scroll being dragged

Tags: javascript, react-native

(I'm currently only interested in iOS behaviour)

I'm importing `ScrollView` from react-native, and would like to detect when scrolling occurs, namely it's dragging, and finishes dragging.

```
 <ScrollView
    onScrollBeginDrag={() => {
      console.log('dragging');
    }}
    onScrollEndDrag={() => {
      console.log('finished');
    }}
  >
```

This works completely fine, except for one use case: if the user scrolls and then tap with the finger to stop the scrolling (instead of just lifting the finger), then the `onScrollEndDrag` will trigger but the single tapping used to stop the scrolling will actually trigger another scrolling event, meaning the `onScrollBeginDrag` will trigger, and immediately after, `onScrollEndDrag` will trigger again.

Is it possible to prevent that second chain of scroll? When the user taps to stop the scrolling, I don't want it to count as another scrolling event.

Comment: You could debounce your actions and only perform the last action in the past second or so.

Comment: @Abe Yes I thought of that, but the user can theoretically click to stop the scrolling after more than one second..thanks anyways